# jQuery count total of each item in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, count

I have the below code where I want to count how many of each class there is and display it in mytotal

```
<ul>
    <li class="myid-1">AAA</li>
    <li class="myid-1">AAA</li>
    <li class="myid-2">BBB</li>
    <li class="myid-1">AAA</li>
</ul>
<div id="mytotal">
    <span id="item-1">AAA</span>
    <span id="item-2">BBB</span>
    <span id="item-3">CCC</span>
</div>

<script>
var id = '';
var cnt = '';

$('li').each(function (index, value) {
    id = jQuery(this).attr('class') || '';
    id = id.replace(/myid-/, '');
    var cnt = jQuery("li.myid-" + id).length;
});

$('#mytotal span').each(function (index, value) {
    id = jQuery(this).attr('id') || '';
    id = id.replace(/aaa-/, '');
    jQuery("#aaa-" + id).append(' (' + cnt + ')');
});
</script>
```

The expected result is the below

```
AAA (3)
BBB (1)
CCC (0)
```

However I am getting

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

I know it is something to do with the way I am using my variables as it is not carrying through, what is the best way to get this working?

Comment: It makes no sense why you would look them up multiple times!

Comment: `cnt` is a local variable in the first `$('li').each(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just think the other way around. You are looping twice which is unnecessary and you set `cnt` which is set on a local variable, and you don't keep track of cnt for each of them. So loop through your target, pick the id part and check for the length of corresponding li counterpart and set its own text accordingly. Plus you can avoid processing the same li for which the length has already been calculated.

```
 $('#mytotal').children().text(function(_, cur){ //.text takes a function arg which is equivalent to doing a loop. cur represents the current test
    var id = this.id.replace(/item-/, ''); //get the part from id
    return cur + "(" + $("li.myid-" + id).length + ")"; //return the new text with old text + the length
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46spt/)**

Comment: +1, Nice one bruv! `:)` special yay for `return cur + "(" + $("li.myid-" + id).length + ")"` `:P`

Answer (score 0):

Using a JavaScript object you can set the text names as keys in the object and then increment the keys as you iterate over the list.

```
var results = {};
var spans = $('#mytotal span').each(function(){
    results[$(this).text()] = 0;
});

$('li').each(function(){
    results[$(this).text()]++;
});

spans.each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    id = el.attr('id') || '';
    id = id.replace(/aaa-/, '');
    jQuery("#aaa-" + id).append(' (' + results[el.text()] + ')');
});
```